# Google Map markers not showing for locations loaded from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Google Maps API for my website with Node.js and mongodb. I have an express app on Node.js that fetches locations from mongodb. I have set up the map on my website. However, it is showing markers only for the locations hard coded in the Node.js code. Here, is the piece of code from routes.js

```
app.get('/website', function(req, res){
    website.website(function(events){
        res.render('website/index_page.ejs', {events : events});
    });
});
```

The index_page.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <% include map_head %> 
</head> 
<body>
    <h2>Events</h2>
    <ol>
        <%events.forEach(function(event){%>
            <li><p><%= event %></p></li>
        <%});%>
    </ol>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:650px;height:700px;"></div>`
</body> 
</html>`
```

And the map_head.ejs

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(10, 90),
            zoom:4,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        events.forEach(function (event) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(event.latitude), Number(event.longitude)),
                map: map,
                title: "test"
            });
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Markers show up if I hardcode the events array rather than fetching from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events object is only known to the server and its ejs parser.

The client does not receive the events object in the code you provided.
It only receives an "ol" list.

Your could include the events object in map_head.ejs with code like this:

```
var events=<%- JSON.stringify(events); %>;
```

Comment: I tried this but the markers are still not showing. I added this in the script labels in map_head.js without <%'s.

Comment: check if events is set, with alert(events); in your html page before using it. Why did you remove the <% ?

Comment: what does it means by "events is set"? I removed <%'s as I added <script> var events=JSON.stringify(events); </script>

Comment: add "alert(events);" before "events.forEach(..." and the browser will show you either "object" or "undefined". 
<%= is necessary because the server has to do the task. The Script tag is not needed, because you can add the line

var events=<%- JSON.stringify(events); %>;

right in the line before "events.forEach(..."